# Htaccess Redirect URL with Parameter

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

What is the proper htaccess command for redirecting the following page with a parameter:

http://www.domain.com/directory/file.php?pageId=1234

to the page:

http://www.domain.com/page.php

Comment: Do you want any `pageId` value i.e. `/directory/file.php?pageId=567` to be redirected to `/page.php` OR only `/directory/file.php?pageId=1234` to be redirected?

Comment: @anubhava only /directory/file.php?pageId=1234

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^directory/file.php.*$ page.php [L,R]
```

Optionally if you want it to be a 'temporary redirect' you can use R=302 instead of R

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+file\.php\?pageId=1234[\s&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page.php? [R=302,L,NE]
```